# Understanding 何かしら思うことはあった?

Tags: grammar, structure

> 桐葉「そう。それなら少し罪悪感も和らぐわ」
>
> 寿季「罪悪感、感じてたんだ？」
>
> 桐葉「私を何だと思ってるのよ。ほんの少しは感じていたわよ」
>
> ほんの少しなんだ…… それでも**何かしら思うことはあった**らしい。

What does the bold part mean? It doesn’t sound right to understand it as "she sometimes thinks of something" in this context. Is it the same as 何かしら思うところはあった?
https://meaning-book.com/blog/20190419173344.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This ことがある does not mean "sometimes", but simply "there is something" (or "she has something"). 何かしら思うこと is "something in mind".

> それでも何かしら思うことはあったらしい。
> Still, she seems to have had (at least) something in mind.

何かしら思うところはあった is a synonym (may sound slightly more euphemistic/polite).

Comment: 何かしら is defined as an adverb/副詞 in dictionaries, but in a lot of cases it seems to modify a noun/noun phrase? Does it modify 思うこと here? Also, here is a similar phrase 「何かしら邪魔がはいれば、なおさら恋しゅうなるもの」. Does it modify the noun 邪魔?

Comment: @EddieKal 何かしら is just a literary/elegant variant of 何か meaning "some(thing)".